# FindHeight (of a binary tree) method always returns 1?

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-tree

```
int findHeight(struct BstNode* root)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        return -1;
    return max(findHeight(root->left),findHeight(root->right))+1;
}
```

The function always returns 1 as the height. 
Here's the code link.
https://github.com/ashwinidotx/OpenIssues/blob/master/Height%20Of%20Binary%20Tree.c

Comment: Please post the full code in the question so it's self-contained. Thank you.

Comment: I added the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is buggy. When you are reaching beyond the leaf node, you are returning `-1` which is wrong. This is doing subtraction on the calculation of tree height. You should simply return `0` here because you hit the end, there is no node down there.

Here is the corrected method:

```
int findHeight(struct BstNode* root)
{
    if(root == NULL)
        return 0;

    return 1 + max(findHeight(root->left), findHeight(root->right));
}
```